Problems with the beforeunload event
I am creating a React website with navigation. I have for example a component in the path /home and another component in the path /compList. I need to get a dialog that when I am specifically in /compList if I press the refresh button or the close browser button or the browser tab, I get a dialog asking me: Are you sure you want to exit?
The problem I have is that when I program this in the /compList component, I make the dialog pop up, press the "cancel" button, navigate to the /home path and try to refresh the page, I get the same dialog again. How can I limit it to a single path?
export default function compList() {

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);

    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("beforeunload",handleBeforeUnload);
    };
}, []);

const handleBeforeUnload = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = "";
    return;
};


You never remove the listener

Why do you say I should never delete the listener?

No, you are never doing that, but you should

function(){} !== function(){}! Simply move your function into a resuable variable const beforeUnloadHandler = (event: any) => ... and then add and remove that to the window events with addEventListener( 'beforeunload' , beforeUnloadHandler ) and  removeEventListener( 'beforeunload', beforeUnloadHandler ). Has React broken your base javascript skills? Because this is what's happening to devs all around me who only know and use React these days. This is core js functionality and fundamental to know about functions...

I have edited the code, but it still does the functionality wrong. Your comment is a bit offensive, I imagine that so much programming with javascript...

I would guess that it's  rather answering the same question every day
